# Cartesian product for an array of json objects

Tags: cartesian-product

How can I produce all of the combinations of the values in an array of the of Objects.

```
var input = [
    { "colour" : "red",
      "material" : "cotton" ,
       "shape" : "round" 
    },
  {   "colour" : "green",
      "material" : "wool" ,
       "shape" : "square" 
    }
];
```

The expected output is the Cartesian product of all the options available, creating a new array with the same keys.

```
var expected = [
    { 'colour': 'red', 'material': 'cotton', 'shape': 'round' },
    { 'colour': 'red', 'material': 'cotton', 'shape': 'square' },
    { 'colour': 'red', 'material': 'wool', 'shape': 'round' },
    { 'colour': 'red', 'material': 'wool', 'shape': 'square' },
    { 'colour': 'green', 'material': 'cotton', 'shape': 'round' },
    { 'colour': 'green', 'material': 'cotton', 'shape': 'square' },
    { 'colour': 'green', 'material': 'wool', 'shape': 'round' },
    { 'colour': 'green', 'material': 'wool', 'shape': 'square' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in two steps:

Step 1: collect all values for each key

```
var options = {};
input.forEach(function (item)
{
  for (var prop in item)
  {
    if (options[prop])
    {
      options[prop].push(item[prop]);
    } else
    {
      options[prop] = [item[prop]];
    }
  }
});
console.log(options);
```

Which will give

```
{ colour: [ 'red', 'green' ],
  material: [ 'cotton', 'wool' ],
  shape: [ 'round', 'square' ] }
```

Step 2: Create the cartesian product by using a triple-nested iteration:

```
  let result = [{}];
  for (var prop in options)
  {
    // For each object in the existing list...
    result = result.map(function (object)    
    {
      // ... create copies of that object for each option for the current key
      return options[prop].map(function (option)
      {
        let newObject = Object.assign({}, object)
        newObject[prop] = option
        return newObject
      })

    })
      // The result is an array of arrays of objects, so flatten it
      .flat()
  }
  console.log(result)
```

Which gives

```
[ { colour: 'red', material: 'cotton', shape: 'round' },
  { colour: 'red', material: 'cotton', shape: 'square' },
  { colour: 'red', material: 'wool', shape: 'round' },
  { colour: 'red', material: 'wool', shape: 'square' },
  { colour: 'green', material: 'cotton', shape: 'round' },
  { colour: 'green', material: 'cotton', shape: 'square' },
  { colour: 'green', material: 'wool', shape: 'round' },
  { colour: 'green', material: 'wool', shape: 'square' } ]
```